# 'heroku local' cannot find module 'load-foreman-procfile'

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm trying to run Heroku applications locally via 'heroku local,' but a missing module error is occurring in the Heroku CLI. Is this a Heroku bug that just needs to be reported or is there something wrong with how things have been setup on my machine (mac)? Any suggestions are appreciated.

In order to ensure my application isn't the problem, I've been debugging this issue with the node application Heroku provides in its getting started guides. Meaning, it already has a Procfile that can be run using default settings.

Things I've tried:

- Re-install node modules for both application and CLI
- Re-install the Heroku CLI

Here's the error:

```
node-js-getting-started [master] :> heroku local
Error: Cannot find module '../../load-foreman-procfile'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.26.1/libexec/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-local/lib/commands/local/index.js:5:18)
```

The file for the route above requires a 'load-foreman-procfile' like so:

```
const Procfile = require('../../load-foreman-procfile');
```

That require path doesn't lead to a to file by that name. In fact, this is the only reference to 'load-foreman-procfile' I can find in '/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.26.1'.

Rather than the error code above, I would expect heroku local to yield a running local server started via my Procfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error running heroku-cli `v7.26.0`. I switched to their edge channel (currently `v7.26.2`) and `heroku local` worked for me after that.

Comment: Thanks @sophon. How did you switch channels? Oddly enough, ```heroku -v``` returns ```7.26.2``` on my end. But the error obviously is looking for information in the 7.26.1 directory.

Comment: For mac I'm not sure. I'm on ubuntu and the way I did it was run 
```sudo snap refresh heroku --classic --edge```

Answer (score 2):

like @sophon mentioned - updating from `v7.26.0` to `v7.26.2` solved this for me. `heroku update` on mac did the trick.